How to preserve case of URL host/domain (URL() constructor)
The URL() constructor normalizes the case of the hostname/domain to lowercase:
(new URL('https://WWW.EXAMPLE.COM/THIS/is/a/PATH')).href
// => 'https://www.example.com/THIS/is/a/PATH'

What is the simplest way to get the hostname and href strings with the case of the hostname preserved? Is there anything better than parsing the domain name manually, then replacing in the result from URL.href?
I would like to query/manipulate a URL (like remove unnecessary query parameters), but preserve the case of the domain. While domains are case-insensitive, sometimes hostnames have uppercase characters thrown in to make them more readable (like expertsexchange.com).

No, I don't think there is anything better. You won't be able to convince URL to not do the lower-casing of the host name.

You can extract it before using the URL constructor and put them back with a replace before showing/assigning it. Also EE added a hyphen, making it "The hyphened site" when the creators of SO did not want to mention the name

And all this hyphen thing was in 1997 or so.

This seemed like the simplest/least error-prone way (no manual URL parsing):


const url = 'https://www.EXAMPLE.com/THIS/is/a/PATH'
console.log(url)

const urlObject = new URL(url)

// 1. Create a case-insensitive regular expression based on URL.hostname.
const hostnameRE = new RegExp(urlObject.hostname, 'i')

// 2. Get the original mixed-cased domain using hostnameRE.
const hostnameOriginalCase = (url.match(hostnameRE))[0]

// Modify URL object:
urlObject.searchParams.set('new', 'param')

// 3. Replace the lowercase domain with the mixed case domain, gain using hostnameRE.
const urlWithOriginalCase = urlObject.href.replace(hostnameRE, hostnameOriginalCase)

// Results:
console.log(urlObject.href)
console.log(urlWithOriginalCase)




Although unlikely to be an issue, you should still escape regex metacharacters.

…or probably even easier still, just not use regex and rather get url.slice(0, urlObject.origin.length + urlObject.pathname.length)
